# JPA, MySql: Partial JSON Update in Entity with Map Property using Criteria API

Tags: spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, mysql-json

```
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "json", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @Convert(converter = HashMapWarehouseConverter.class)
    private Map<String, ProductWarehouseDto> warehousesRemote;
}

public class ProductWarehouseDto {
    private String warehouse;
    private Double stock;
}

@Converter
public class HashMapWarehouseConverter extends BaseJsonJpaConverter<Map<String, ProductWarehouseDto>> {
    public HashMapWarehouseConverter() {
        super(new TypeReference<>() {
        });
    }
}


var update = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Product.class);
var root = update.from(Product.class);

Path<Integer> versionPath = root.get("version");
Expression<Integer> incrementVersion = builder.sum(1, versionPath);

update.where(builder.equal(root.get("id"), product.getId()))
        .set(versionPath, incrementVersion);


if (product.getWarehousesRemote() != null) {
    Path<String> wrPath = root.get("warehousesRemote");

    var caseExpression = builder.selectCase()
            .when(builder.isNull(wrPath), "{}")
            .otherwise(wrPath);

    product.getWarehousesRemote().forEach((key, value) -> {
        var jsonKey = builder.literal("$." + key);

        var jsonArgs = List.of("warehouse", value.getWarehouse(), "stock", value.getStock());
        var jsonObject = builder.function("JSON_OBJECT", String.class, builder.literal(jsonArgs));

        var jsonSet = builder.function("JSON_SET", String.class, caseExpression, jsonKey, jsonObject);

        update.set(wrPath, jsonSet);
    });
}

entityManager.createQuery(update).executeUpdate();
```

Hello!

I have a 'Product' entity that contains a map of balances. This map stores warehouse identifiers along with ProductWarehouseDto data, which is saved in the database as JSON. I'm looking for a way to partially update this JSON.

I've implemented a method that accomplishes this task, but I'm unsatisfied because each field of the JSON object requires a separate query. I haven't been able to create a single method that assembles the JSON using the Criteria API.

Could anyone advise if there's a way to achieve this?
What other approaches could be more efficient for solving this problem?

Spring Boot 2.7, MySql 5.7.

Thank you in advance!